# In PHP is it possible to use the browser from the command line and bring the results?

Tags: php, browser, command-line

Well, i need(no wanna, need) open for example Google Chrome from command line and get results with javascript and iframes enabled.

Example:
A site have jQuery ajax request and create iframes, and this iframes have another iframe with another pure javascript. This last javascript generate a table with thead, te, th, tbody, te and td with texts and anchors.

So, i think In :

```
$browser = new Browser("//site.com/a/b/c/D/index.html");
$browser->input('hello');
$browser->click('form [type=submit]');
//after click, form send ajax post request and inser iframe with iframes and table ...
$browser->getResults();
```

Please, help me, Thanks

PS: stackexchange for mobile cant support 'https' on body... So real url In the example have https.

Comment: Try to search in google `php browser emulation` already found 2 projects, one with javascript support and another with iframes support. See if you have better luck.

Comment: Something like http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/?